# How to drive power MOSFET at 1 MHz

Tags: rf, oscillator, mosfet-driver

As part of a radio transmitter design, a square wave oscillator has to drive a power mosfet. Given the gate capacitance and the frequency, the maximum current should be around 50mA.

The power mosfet is a little bit of an overkill (it works up to 2A), but RF mosfets don't go as high as I need, at least not the one I have. The oscillator can't source that much current, so I need a buffer that can source 50mA at 1MHz. The only buffers I know how to build are BJT followers with a common emitter, but they aren't fast enough. When switching it on and off, it takes time for it to go up to VCC again.

Comment: Try searching for "MOSFET gate driver".

Comment: I did, I could only find ICs that I cannot buy where I live. I could order them from Digikey or something but shipping is insanely expensive. Do you know any MOSFET driver fast enough and really popular? Some popular ICs are findable around here

Comment: Why not build yourself a totem-pole driver with a 2N2222/2N2907 complementary pair or parallel enough CMOS gates to drive the MOSFET gate?

Comment: I have seen many industrial induction heating devices, but at 1Mhz there are just vacuum tubes. You won't find any ready made gate driver for that frequency, perhaps you should look in some Tesla coil builders forum.

Comment: [Maybe try this?](http://www.micrel.com/_PDF/mic4451.pdf)

Comment: For a small MOSFET, it does not take much to get it to switch at 1 MHz efficiently as your 50mA calculation has shown. As EM Fields has suggested, just parallel couple of CMOS gates or use a pair of NPN/PNP transistors. I would arrange both transistors in emitter follower configuration (unless you have a gate voltage level issue to start with).

Answer (score 1):

I have done the 'roll-your own' MOSFET driver and it works well enough for frequencies below ~16kHz, but to drive at 1MHz, you will need a MOSFET driver for sure.  Fast switching times will be critical and the roll-your-own method will not be adequate.

The recommendations that I'm giving are typically used for a half-bridge setup (DC-DC converters, motor drives, etc.), but should lead you down the right paths.

I have used the [FAN7842MX](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/fairchild-semiconductor/FAN7842MX/FAN7842MXCT-ND/1642608) successfully for frequencies up to 60kHz on TO-220 packages (lots of capacitance to overcome).  It only has about 300mA of instantaneous gate drive current.

The [IR2011](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/infineon-technologies-americas-corp/IR2011STRPBF/IR2011SPBFCT-ND/827938) series would probably be better.  It has 1A gate drive current capability.

I can't remember the part number, but there are some with higher ability to drive the circuit.  At 1MHz, you need a solid gate drive.